# Error in Javascript: Object not defined

Tags: javascript

I have following Html file with javascript. This gives me error that "testCircle is undefined." kinldy help me resolve this.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1> Testing Object-based Javascipt </h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mycircle(x,y,r)
    {
    this.xcoord=x;
    this.ycoord=y;
    this.radius=r;
    this.area = getArea;
    this.getCircumference = function () { return (2 * Math.PI * this.radius ) ; };
    }
   function getArea()
   {
   return (Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius);
   }
        var testCircle = mycircle(3,4,5);

   window.alert('The radius of my circle is ' + testCircle.radius);

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: ..and what does `mycircle()` return? Exactly - nothing (`undefined`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var testCircle = mycircle(3, 4, 5);
```

should be

```
var testCircle = new mycircle(3, 4, 5);
```

Constructors are to be called with the `new` keyword. If the keyword is not used, you're assigning the return value of the `mycircle` function. And as `mycircle` contains no `return` statement, the return values is `undefined` - that's what you assigned to `testCircle` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error I'm getting is radius of undefined. If this is the case. You need to return this at the end of mycircle if you planned to use it without new constructor.

As seen on [updated: this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UZYff/1/).

Fix: Broken link

Comment: This is a wrong way of creating an object. In your code, `mycircle` is called in the global context, so `this` refers to `window`. You're appending the `xcoord, ycoord, ...` etc. properties to the `window` object and returning a reference to it. The whole circle is thus kept as a set of properties of `window` and another call to `mycircle` will overwrite it.

Comment: forgive me for the incomplete fiddle. assuming the object does created in the local scope. as I've just copy the code and paste them to test. it was meant to return mycircle. but you are right.